# How to make time as variable in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, time

I need to title graphs dynamically in following pattern:

```
date time symbol
```

I take these values as variables from certain cells in worksheet and I'm stuck with a time variable. It doesn't read hour as, for example `09:26:51` but as decimal value `0,3`..etc

Last thing I came up to is:

```
Dim tim As Date
tim = TimeValue(Range("b2").Value)
```

I believe it's an easy one to solve.

Comment: Oh, funny thing, just figured it out myself by deleting "TimeValue" lol

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Format()** function for example:

```
MyNewTime = Format(MyTime, "h:m:s")    ' Returns "17:4:23".
MyNewtime = Format(MyTime, "hh:mm:ss AMPM")    ' Returns "05:04:23 PM".
```